# Dynamics CRM Plugin Trace log record throwing Access Denied error for System Administrator

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

Its really weird to see **Access Denied** error for System Administrator in CRM.

When trying to open any record from Plugin trace logs, system throws the below error in our dev environment.

[image]

> Access Is Denied
>
> You do not have enough privileges to access the Microsoft Dynamics CRM object or perform the requested operation. For more information, contact your Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrator.

Unable to verify the missing access rights as there is no 'Download Log' button, platform trace cannot be checked since this is CRM online. I don't see any relationship control issue like lookup/subgrid in this OOB entity.

Also if you see the page title, it says Dashboard - fishy? Any pointers to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crazy, when we try to delete the Plugin trace log entries, it says the most useful message:

> Not enough privilege to access the Microsoft Dynamics CRM object or perform the requested operation. The current Organizationid '79bd6aa8-984f-4d51-ae47-0a178c71d762' does not match with userOrTeam's organization id '760ed188-468e-40ca-86bd-ceca16ee64a1'.

So these were **moved as part of sandbox refresh from another instance**. Damn, then why they are showing in this org grid beyond POA; MS can answer it, probably they will solve this platform bug as its not allowing to delete because of POA.