# BulkDeleteFailureBase - lots of "Not Enough Privilege" records

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I've taken over support of a CRM 2016 On-Premise system. I don't know the history of the particular instance, but I suspect it's been copied and/or imported many times.

The BulkDeleteFailureBase tables has just short of 2 million rows, almost all of which contain an error description like:

> Not enough privilege to access the Microsoft Dynamics CRM object or
>   perform the requested operation. The current Organizationid '<GUID1>'
>   does not match with userOrTeam's organization id '<GUID2>'.

OrganisationBase has only one record with `<GUID2>` in it.

Has this happened because the instance has been copied/moved around incorrectly? If so, is this likely an indication more problems are heading my way in the future?

How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

`BulkDeleteFailureBase` is one of the system async jobs logging table where platform captures the run/success/failure logs.

Probably someone might have tried to clean the data like [Plugin Trace log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283332/7920473) which were copied over from different DB backup/restore or CRM Org restoration. They used Bulk delete & all that fails, ended up here.

[MS Support recommendation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968520/performance-is-slow-if-the-asyncoperationbase-table-becomes-too-large) gives the script to clean those tables safely. Leaving it only gives you performance head-ache.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried the linked script. It clears out some of the records, but not the ones causing this particular problem.

Comment: @MattDuFeu in that case, you can create a ticket with MS & solve this issue.